# Sending Command with CR to TCP server in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, printing, tcp

```
public void ClientSend(string msg)
{
    stream = client.GetStream(); //Gets The Stream of The Connection
    byte[] data; // creates a new byte without mentioning the size of it cuz its a byte used for sending
    data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg); // put the msg in the byte ( it automaticly uses the size of the msg )
    int length = data.Length; // Gets the length of the byte data
    byte[] datalength = new byte[4]; // Creates a new byte with length of 4
    datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length); //put the length in a byte to send it
    stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4); // sends the data's length
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //Sends the real data
}
```

I am trying to send commands to **Videojet Printer TTO** which is TCP server in my case when I send `GST<cr>` through hercules (TCP Client) it send command properly to the printer as GST where as when I send `textbox.text = "GST" + "\r"` from my C# TCP Client utility Printer doesn't responds. It is observed in Hercules that when I send `textbox.text = "GST" + "\r"` in Hercules TCP server it recieves as `GST\r` not as GST that means CR is passing with the String it is going as a string.

```
richtextbox.AppendText("\r\n" + now.ToString() + " Sent : \r\n" + textbox.Text + "\r");
```

Comment: The code you've shown is only about the RichTextBox. You haven't shown anything about how you're sending the text to the server... (I suspect you want to use the `Lines` property and join the lines together with `\n`.)

Comment: *Please* stop using JavaScript code snippets for C# code. I've already removed it once... you should *only* claim that something is a JS code snippet when it really is

Comment: I'd also very strongly recommend that you stop using `Encoding.Default` - you're sending data to a server... do you really want your client platform to matter? (Also, your comments are incorrect - `byte[] data` doesn't create "a new byte" or even "a new byte array" - it just declares a variable without initializing it.)

Comment: Have you tried using `@` before the `\r` ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically it sounds like you need to change how you're handling the text from the `RichTextBox`. If you want to use `\r` as a line-break, use:

```
string text = string.Join("\r", richtextbox.Lines);
ClientSend(text);
```

As mentioned in comments, you almost certainly *don't* want to use `Encoding.Default`... you should find out what encoding the server is expecting, and use that. If you can specify that yourself, I'd use UTF-8:

```
// Note: there's no benefit in declaring the variable in one statement
// and then initializing it in the next.
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
```

Comment: I want to send CR with the command to TCP server my commad is GST<cr>

Comment: @RushaliWatane: Will if you call `ClientSend("GST\r")` that will do the right thing... it's not clear where the rich text box comes into this... but basically I'd be very cautious about anything where you get text *out* of a textbox. You shouldn't rely on line-breaks being what you originally specified them as in that case.

Comment: When I pass directly ClientSend("GST\r") it sends but through ClientSend(textbox.text + @"\r") where textbox.text = GST is not working

Comment: Hey, ClientSend(textbox.text + '\r') did the thing for me thanks for your support

Comment: @Rushali: Well yes, using `@"\r"` would send a backslash followed by an r, which isn't what you want, which is why I never suggested it...

Answer (score 0):

instead of sending "GST" + "\r" try to send "GST" + (char)13;.